# Refer to adjacent term of a Python iterable while in a for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iterable

This is a really basic syntax question that I just don't know how to do/can't figure out how to look for an explanation of.  Basically, you can really easy compare/compute things between successive terms of an iterable with, say, this:

```
for i in range(len(iterable)):
    if iterable[i] == iterable[i + 1]:
        do whatever
```

but it seems like there definitely ought to be a way to do that without messing about with the range(len()) thing? like, i ought to be able to have

```
for item in iterable:
    if item == nextitem:
        do whatever
```

except that "nextitem" would be some sort of keyword or a slice syntax or...I don't really know what it would be, I just feel like it has to exist. i thought `for item, nextitem in iterable` might work but that only seems to refer to tuples INSIDE the iterable. What am I looking for here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's not a built in way to do it, but this works:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
for item, nextitem in izip_longest(iterable, iterable[1:]):
    if item == nextitem:
        do whatever better
```

[izip_longest docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest)

depending on what your iterable actually is, you could do `zip(iterable[:-1], iterable[1:])`

Comment: i had not thought of using zip! it still seems weird that something more intuitive wouldn't be built in? but if it's not, it's not. the zip thing would work and it's less gross than the range(len()) thing i had at first; thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the complaint. `zip` is a builtin function.

Comment: yes, but i don't consider the method using zip to be especially intuitive. it seems weird that something more intuitive than using zip isn't built in.